# Как парсить одну строку с одинаковыми тегами Python

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

[image]

есть сайт центробанка, мне нужно из него спарсить евро и доллар, зашёл в код, увидел там такую картину, так как я недавно начал изучать тему Парсинга, я не знаю как решить этот вопрос, буду рад вашей помощи, парсить нужно исключительно цена евро и доллара

Comment: Выделить таблицу как список списков. Список строк, каждая строка содержит несколько столбцов. А затем уже перебрать полученный массив и удалить все строки, первый(или какой там не знаю) элемент этой строки не равен USD или EU.

Comment: Ну вы бы ссылку на сайт хоть привели. Возможно, там вообще через `pandas` элементарно будет всё вытянуть.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for q in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    # id, letter_id, unit, name, course = [x.text for x in q.find_all('td')]
    id, letter_id, unit, name, course = map(lambda x: x.text, q.find_all('td'))
    if letter_id == 'USD' or letter_id == 'EUR':
        print(name, course)
```